# ProgressDialog does not showing Title and Message

Tags: android, progressdialog, progress

Hope all are playing well with Errors.

I am stuck with silly problem. I don't know why it is happening?

I have created one `AsyncTask` in that i am doing process of uploading images.

```
   /**
     * Uploading Images
     */
    private class UploadPhotosTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        String errorMessage;
        ArrayList<PhotoCaption> captionArrayList;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        private UploadPhotosTask(ArrayList<PhotoCaption> arrayList) {
            captionArrayList = arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumPhotoDetailsActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Wait for a while");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Photos...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.setMax(captionArrayList.size());
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

             //Processing for upload
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't showing **Title** or **Message**, I dont know why.

> Note: I have tried all the possibilities. If i remove
>   `setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)` it is displaying
>   circular progress but i want here Horizontal ProgressBar with Number
>   of Images which are ready to upload.

[image]

Any Idea? Why It is so? Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: remove progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true); and try

Comment: i can see it , that means it is theme issue on your end,probably textcolor set to white

Comment: @ankitagrawal You are awesome at all :) Thank you so much for saving my time. :) :) I have defined `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>` which is white. So sorry for disturbing you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is theme issue on your end,probably `textcolor` set to white in your theme change these

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

change it to black

Answer (score 0):

Its all about theme problem as i have defined in my **`style.xml`**

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
```

where `colorPrimaryText` have white color. I have just removed that lines.